# How to copy an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, stack, gdi+

I am trying to create a temporary array

```
Stack<Point[]> v = new Stack<Point[]>();
Point[] c= new Point[4];
```

then store it in a stack

```
v.Push(c);
```

but every time I try to modify the array, it also modify every `instance` inside the stack.

```
c[state] = mouse;
```

Is there a way to copy it into the stack?

Comment: Do you understand that right now your stack is storing an array reference, not an array?  If you want to store a reference to a new copy of the array, you have to make that new copy.

Comment: What's `Point`? Also, arrays only hold *references* to objects, not the objects themselves

Comment: sorry for the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I was trying to store a Bézier segment in the array, then store it in the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because arrays are references type you use the same instance, so every time I  modify the array, it also modifies every instance inside the stack.

I would create a new instance array to `Stack` instead of `c`, It can split two array.

```
Stack<Point[]> v = new Stack<Point[]>();
Point[] c = new Point[4];
v.Push(new Point[4]);
c[0] = new Point(1, 1);
```

if there are some data in `c` `Point[]`, you can try to use `CopyTo` to copy the data to another array.

```
Stack<Point[]> v = new Stack<Point[]>();
Point[] c = new Point[4];

Point[] pushArr = new Point[c.Length];
c.CopyTo(pushArr, 0);
v.Push(pushArr);
```

Comment: `v.Push(new Point[4]);
c = v.Last();`
Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Your stack only keeps the reference to the array. You have to create a copy of the array.

```
Stack<Point[]> v = new Stack<Point[]>();
Point[] c = new Point[4];
v.Push(c);

c[0] = new Point(5, 5);
Point[] cc = new Point[c.Length];
Array.Copy(c, cc, c.Length);
cc[0] = cc[0];

c[0].X = 20;
c[0].Y = 20;
var cx = v.Pop();

Console.WriteLine(c[0]);
Console.WriteLine(cx[0]);
Console.WriteLine(cc[0]);
```

EDIT: the result:

```
{X=20,Y=20}
{X=20,Y=20}
{X=5,Y=5}
```

Comment: im getting {20,20}
{20,20}
{20,20}

Answer (score 0):

When you say that:

```
int[] arr1=arr2;
```

It does not simply copy the data of one variable to another, it store a reference instead.

The solution to my problem is:

```
v.Push(new Point[4]);
Point[] c = v.Last();
```

Here i am referring 'c' to the last variable of my stack.

What was happening before is that i was referring every single variable of my stack to 'c'.